# How to analyze a document from blob using Form-Recognizer Microsoft-Cognitive?

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

I am using Microsoft-Cognitive service (Form-Recognizer) to analyze the document and read its content for further operations. I wanted to analyze the pdf file which is uploaded at the blob.

I am able to get the content using local file path but once I am providing the blob URL then it is not able to open the file.

file-path looks like: https:\blob\SupplierformUpdate1.pdf

```
curl: (26) couldn't open file: the File path
```

I have trained it properly and got the model id.

I tried an analyze service.

```
curl -X POST "https://<Endpoint>/formrecognizer/v1.0-preview/custom/models/<modelID>/analyze" -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" -F "form=@\"<path to your form>\";type=<file type>" -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: <subscription key>"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/quickstarts/curl-train-extract#train-a-form-recognizer-model

I want to get the content by providing the blob URL of the pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

To analyze a form and extract data with Form Recognizer you can send the file as a multipart/form.

Comment: I am using this with multipart/form-part already, but it is not accepting blob URL.

Comment: If you are using multipart/form-data, you are including the file in your POST request, so there is no "url" that is not accepted